# Failed to create CoreCLR error when I add readonlyrootfilesystem: true to kubernetes deployment yaml

Tags: .net, kubernetes, azure-aks

So I have a simple dotnet app that basically logs helloworld

```
namespace HelloWorld;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hello = true;
        while (hello)
        {
            string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World! The time at this moment is: " + str);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120 * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I use docker-compose to build my container and then use a helm upgrade to deploy to kubernetes (AKS).

The issue is that I need to make the filesystem read only.  So I added this to my kubernetes deployment yaml

```
readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

I added the above under my security context for the container.

Now when I deploy to AKS the deployment fails with

```
Back-off restarting failed container helloworld in pod helloworld
```

If I check the logs it shows

```
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005
```

How can I have the app run with readonlyrootfilesystem enabled?